# Full Calendar with Required JS + Angular AMD

Tags: jquery, angularjs, requirejs, fullcalendar

Previously, I was using only angular js with fullcalendar, that time all menu action menu with data-calendar-view attribute were working.

```
'<ul class="actions actions-alt" id="fc-actions">' +
        '<li class="dropdown" dropdown>' +
        '<a href="" dropdown-toggle><i class="zmdi zmdi-more-vert"></i></a>' +
        '<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">' +
        '<li class="active">' +
        '<a data-calendar-view="month" href="">Month View</a>' +
        '</li>' +
        '<li>' +
        '<a data-calendar-view="basicWeek" href="">Basic Week View</a>' +
        '</li>' +
        '<li>' +
        '<a data-calendar-view="agendaWeek" href="">Full Week View</a>' +
        '</li>' +
        '<li>' +
        '<a data-calendar-view="basicDay" href="">Basic Day View</a>' +
        '</li>' +
        '<li>' +
        '<a data-calendar-view="agendaDay" href="">Full Day View</a>' +
        '</li>' +
        '</ul>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</li>';
```

I am calling

```
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', attrs.calendarView);
```

This function in directive.

But after that I modify my project and add requiredjs and angular AMD in it for loading js when required.

All other code remain same, calendar is loading in UI but the function is not executing and not even throwing any error.

Please help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

The code provided is insufficient to provide you with a thorough answer but for your code to fail this way there are only a few options

1. Your directive is not rendered so `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', attrs.calendarView);` is not called at all

Check if the directive is executed either with developer tools breakpoint or poor man debugging - `console.log` if it's the directive template that should call the function then be sure you make it in `link` method of directive as it's called post render

2. Your directive is rendered but `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', attrs.calendarView);` is called before `#calendar` is present in DOM,

Check if $('#calendar') is present before executing the fullCalendar
`$('#calendar')` would return jQuery object without any elements and `fullCalendar` would be called without throwing errors, if it's DOM racing issue then doing:

```
$timeout(function(){
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', attrs.calendarView);
});
```

Should help as executing this fragment in `$timeout` will schedule it for next `$digest` call